# Sample Ruby Application

Tags: ruby

I'm going to learn Ruby to use Ruby on Rails in future to look for new horizons. I've read a lot about Ruby, but... I doesn't found any real applications that are built with Ruby? For Mac I've found only CLI apps.

Does anyone have use cases for pure (and popular) Ruby applications?

Comment: I've found plenty of sample Ruby applications here: https://www.google.com/#q=ruby+sample+code

Comment: I don't look for any simple examples, I'm looking for REAL Applications that are written in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of [large scale Ruby applications](https://www.google.com/#q=large+scale+ruby+applications), too.

Comment: Wow, eBooks, HowTos, Monitoring, Tutorials, ... but ... wait ... any application that I'm looking for? No! So please stop spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling for "ruby code for applications"

I found this:

http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/Ruby/

If your ultimate goal is Rails applications, I would learn that at the same time (that search is easy too.  Many folks start with the famous hartl tutorials and Ryan Bates Railscasts), particularly to get experience with the miriad conventions that you need to know to write good rails apps.  If you got good at ruby first you could end up writing a lot of code in rails apps... that could be written for you via rails conventions and external gems.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to learn both stacks simultaneously. The ruby you need for bread and butter work on Rails is not that complicated. Furthermore Rails is very centered on the framework itself. Unless you need to write your own GEMs (plugins) you will not dive too deeply into the ruby part.

A good start for Rails are the courses mentioned here:

http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts

For specialized knowledge I can only emphasize Ryan's Railscasts listed there.

For books I recommend the Galileo Computing "Ruby on Rails" books. For Rails 2 there is a free version online. For 3.x, which you prpbably want to use, you have to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend [Ruby Best Practices](http://rubybestpractices.com/), good guide how to build applications.

Comment: I don't want to know HOW to build. I want to see done ruby apps